# Windows Custom Event Log doesn't show on Task Manager

Tags: windows, powershell, event-handling, scheduled-tasks

I've written a Custom Event Log "MyTestLog" using PowerShell, a custom Event View to show events and some Scheduled Jobs to be trigged against events in "MyTestLog". However, I've to manually make a XML query to MyTestLog for every to-be-scheduled job, since MyTestLog doesn't show in dropdown menu inside the Task Scheduler, within Application, System Events and so on. In other words, I had to use this xquery as trigger:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="MyTestLog">*[System[Provider[@Name='MyTestLog'] and (Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4 or Level=0 or Level=5)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

It's definitively very tedious to me; is there a way to show up MyTestLog in dropdowns (both in event viewer and task scheduler)?

Answer (score 0):

What OS is this on?  I just tested on my W7 machine, and after creating a new event log, I can create a Custom View in Event View to include this log, and it shows up on the dropdown menu in Task Scheduler if I configure an event trigger on a task.

Comment: Appears to be OS specific, and I don't have one of those to test on.  Sorry.